# Ext Window is not coming in center after browser resizing

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, extjs6-classic

I have a window which is not coming in center after browser resizing. When I resizing the browser half of the window getting disappear

```
var Win,
    ViewPort = Ext.getBody(),
    winWidth = ViewPort.getWidth(),
    winHeight = ViewPort.getHeight();
Win = new Ext.IframeWindow({
                        id: 'H1',
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: true,
                        title: 'H1',
                        closable: true,
                        constrain : true,
                    });
    Win.width = (winWidth / 100) * 90,
    Win.height = (winHeight / 100) * 90,
```

Also when I am giving width and height by some percentage like

```
Win.width = '80%',
Win.height = '90%',
```

In this case is coming fine. But I don't want because of data and layout adjusment on window.

Comment: As per my Understanding you asking to resize your win on complete browser resize

Comment: Yes, I want window in center on browser resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need to get new viewport(as per your code) of resized browser and then you have to set new width and height for win.

Here is the method you can use

```
window.onresize=function(obj){
    var viewport =  Ext.getBody();
    var H1Window = Ext.getCmp('H1');
    var H1WindowWidth = viewport.getWidth();
    var H1WindowHeight = viewport.getHeight();
    if(H1Window){
        H1Window.setWidth((bioMarkerWindowWidth / 100) * 90);
        H1Window.setHeight((bioMarkerWindowHeight / 100) * 90);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try below code snippet:-

1. By using window id:

   `Ext.getBody().el.dom.onresize = function() {
        if(Ext.getCmp('your_window_id')) {
             Ext.getCmp('your_window_id').center();
        }
   }`
2. By using window itemId:

   `Ext.getBody().el.dom.onresize = function() {
        if(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#your_window_id')[0]) {
             Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#your_window_id')[0].center();
        }
   }`

Hope this help you :)

Answer (score -1):

Take a looke at the [anchorTo](http://devdocs.local/extjs-620-docs/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#method-anchorTo) method. This should work:

```
win.anchorTo(Ext.getBody(), win.defaultAlign);
```

Comment: This is creating window below the actual application. Ideally window should open on top of application

Comment: Check out this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1nor). Seems to work..